# mysql return results by key grouping

Tags: mysql, sql, pdo

I have this **league_table**:

```
+--------+----------+-------------+
|   id   |   star   |   section   |
+--------+----------+-------------+
|   1    |    1     |      A      |
|   2    |    0     |      A      |
|   3    |    1     |      B      |
|   4    |    1     |      B      |
|   5    |    0     |      C      |
|   6    |    1     |      C      |
|   7    |    0     |      D      |
|   8    |    1     |      D      |
+--------+----------+-------------+
```

I am wondering if this is possible, can I have a return in which they are returned in groups?

Say if I do this simple query `SELECT id, star FROM league_table WHERE star = 1"` then use `PDO FETCH ALL`

I can have this output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [star] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [star] => 1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4
            [star] => 1
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 6
            [star] => 1
        )
    [4] => Array
        (
            [id] => 8
            [star] => 1
        )
)
```

However, can I have this output so that it is more organized?

```
Array
(
    [A] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array 
                (
                  [id] => 1
                  [star] => 1
                )
        )

    [B] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                   [id] => 3
                   [star] => 1
                )
            [1] => Array
                (
                   [id] => 4
                   [star] => 1
        )

    [C] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array 
                (
                  [id] => 6
                  [star] => 1
                )
        )

    [D] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array 
                (
                  [id] => 8
                  [star] => 1
                )
        )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to organize it like that in your code. 
`SELECT id, star, section FROM league_table WHERE star = 1 order by section asc` will make it a bit simpler for you.

If you're using php, it could look something like this

```
foreach ($result as $key=>$row){
    $output[$row['section']][]=$row;
}
```

Comment: It will just be sorted, it will not separate each id to its section :(

Comment: correct, you'll have to do that in code. I added an example in php

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple solution for this but not what you need

```
SELECT 
    group_concat(id) as IDs,
    star,
    group_concat(section) as Sections
FROM
     league_table
WHERE star = 1
```

This will give you the following output

```
IDs        star    Sections
1,3,4,6,8  1       A,B,B,C,D
```

As you can see IDs and Sections are of same number therefore you can use for loop and access both of them after if you convert the comma seperated fields(IDs , Sections) to arrays.

Comment: Great point in there. Is it possible to put a `SELECT` inside that `group_concat` ?

Answer (score 0):

use can use following SQL.

```
select group_concat(id), star, section from league_table where star = 1' group by section

//you will get the following result

+--------+----------+-------------+
|   id   |   star   |   section   |
+--------+----------+-------------+
|   1    |    1     |      A      |
|   3,4  |    1     |      B      |
|   6    |    1     |      C      |
|   8    |    1     |      D      |
+--------+----------+-------------+
```

Now you can explode(',', id) whenever you iterate through each row. star does not matter much as all values equal to 1